# How to rank (prioritize) values from numbered checkbox form in PHP

Tags: php, checkbox, echo, ranking

I am using the code below to ask users to rank which programming language they are more comfortable with.
The users need to rank from 1-3 (1 being the one they are most comfortable with)

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<input type="number" name="php" required="required" max="3" min="1"/>PHP     <br />
<input type="number" name="python" required="required" max="3" min="1"/>Python <br />
<input type="number" name="ruby" required="required" max="3" min="1"/>Ruby <br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Once the user prioritizes the programming languages and hits submit, how can I on the next page echo the ranking selection? (e.g. Your first choice is x, your second choice is y and your third choice is z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like so (Note that I've changed the the value of the name attributes on the form elements):

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<input type="number" name="lang[php]" required="required" max="3" min="1"/>PHP     <br />
<input type="number" name="lang[python]" required="required" max="3" min="1"/>Python <br />
<input type="number" name="lang[ruby]" required="required" max="3" min="1"/>Ruby <br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And in the php:

```
//Get the form results (which has been converted to an associative array) from the $_POST super global
$langs = $_POST['lang'];

//Sort the values by rank and keep the key associations.
asort($langs, SORT_NUMERIC );

//Loop over the array in rank order to print out the values.
foreach($langs as $lang => $rank)
{
   //echo out here first, second, and third rank with each iteration respectively.
}
```

The [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) function simply sorts the array by value while maintaining key association.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that tag input type="number" exists.

you do better

```
<legend>
<label><input type="radio" name="php" value="1">1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="php" value="2">2</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="php" value="3">3</label>
</legend>

 <legend>
<label><input type="radio" name="python" value="1">1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="python" value="2">2</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="python" value="3">3</label>
</legend>
```

you must not use 'required' attribute for radio tag or checkbox tag

so you make a check javascript function whether radio box is checked or not.

```
<form name..... onsubmit = "return check_submit();">
<script>
var check_submit = function(){
  if($("input[name=php]:checked").val() =="")
  return false;
...
 return true;
}
</script>
```

or you can use

```
<input type="text" name="php">
```

then on next page you can do like this

```
$php = intval(trim($_POST['php']));
$python = intval(trim($_POST['python']));

$msg = "your first choice for php is '.$php;
$msg.="your second choice for phthon is '.$python;

.....etc..
```

Comment: Both the 'number' type and the required attribute are valid HTML.

Comment: ok thanks. i just said required attribute should not be used in radio and checkbox tag.